# Workflow Instance ID with REST api

Tags: workflow, rest

I have a Approve/Reject workflow attached to a library. Is there a way to get the Workflow Instance Id from the list item using REST API?

I know it is possible with 'SPListItem.Workflows' in server-side API but in my case I need a REST equivalent.

Idea is to query Workflow History list with "List" and "WorkflowInstance" columns.

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**: **Workflow Instance Id from the list item**

Make a GET request to the following URL, you will get two fields name `WorkflowInstanceID` and `WorkflowVersion` along with other columns.

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Your Library Name')/Fields
```

So you can get Workflow Instance Ids for all items in your library by following URL

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Your Library Name')/Items?$select=WorkflowInstanceID
```

For a particular Item, let say ID of the Item is 11

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Your Library Name')/Items(11)?$select=WorkflowInstanceID
```

**Question 2: Idea is to query Workflow History**

**Workflow History** is just a list like any other list. So you can apply same idea over here also.

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Workflow History')/Items
```

Comment: Hi Atish, thank you for your suggestion. In fact I tried that but due to some reason WorkflowInstanceId is coming as null when I retrieved list items.

Answer (score 1):

In a SharePoint list if you attach any workflow it will a column with your workflow name. It is a Hyperlink column which can be used to get that full url to query workflow history list.

See below screenshot how it returns results from REST call.

[image]

I have used below query to get that

```
<<site url>>/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('<<list title>>')/Items(<<item id>>)
```

It returns all columns but from results you will get that workflow column